# Json decode with unicode flag in php makes object not iterable

Tags: php, json

I am getting a JSON object from a function in php,

```
$jsonObject = someFunc();
```

then I decode the JSON object as,

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Now, I am unable to iterate of access any properties of this $jsonObject variable.
If I do

```
($jsonObject->attr1)
```

it gives me empty
if a property is an array and I do

```
count($jsonObject->attr2)
```

it returns 0.

However, if I try encoding it and writing it to a file it writes the data in the variable,

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($jsonOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Writes the file with contents of the variable.

I am confused as to why I am not able to iterate or access the decoded JSON object.

P.S. - If I decode without the flag, like:

```
$jsonObject = someFunc();
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonOutput);
```

Then I can access and iterate over the JSON object,
But I need the flag to take into account non-English characters in the data.

*EDIT* : this happens even if I use this:

```
$jsonOutput = json_decode($jsonOutput, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

as pointed out by @u_mulder

Comment: without the actual data it will be hard to help

Comment: Second argument to `json_decode` is a __bool__ value. And not your `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` constant.

Comment: Share the "someFunc()" function to help you more  (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: someFunc() can be an API call to an external system. Assume it is returning a valid json string.